# How to remove this unit production while converting cfg to cnf

Tags: context-free-grammar, chomsky-normal-form

In the grammar I have a rule "`D → bD | D`". How do I remove unit production from this rule for converting it to cnf?

The grammar is this:

```
S → DBC | Ba 
B → 0B1 | 01 | 
C → aCb | aC | Bb 
D → bD | D
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The production `D → D` does not contribute anything to the grammar, so you can just delete it. Moreover, the nonterminal `D` is useless because it cannot derive any sentence; it has no non-recursive production.

Before removing unit productions, you should first reduce your grammar by removing unproductive and unreachable productions.